Fix christmas lights when AC voltage adapter shows no breaks
Why might an entire strand of Christmas lights remain off when a non-contact AC Voltage Detector beeps when placed next to each wire and bulb?
(I know that Christmas lights are cheap. At this point, I'm curious why what I'm doing isn't working.)
I have four strands of Christmas lights that don't light up. My Craftsman non-contact voltage detector beeps regardless of where I point it on the strand of lights (bulb, wires, etc.). I have also tested a few bulbs on other strands of lights, and they aren't burnt out. So, if some of the bulbs work, and none of the shunts appear to be broken, what else could be going on?
I suppose the voltage detector could be broken, but I was able to use it to find the broken bulbs on several other strands of lights.

A non-contact AC voltage detector won't find a break in series-string lamps if the wires are twisted together and the break is past the half-way point of the hot wire, because, for the whole length of the paired wires, there is at least one wire that is hot.

If the plug is non-polarized, reverse it in the outlet so that the hot wire is interrupted before the end.

I still think I'm doing something wrong. Bulbs/wires that are "cold" one minute are "hot" the next. How much do I need to isolate a wire so I don't detect voltage on a different wire? How much do I have to untwist the wires?  (Can a wire that is twisted around another induce an otherwise "cold" wire to cause the detector to light up?)

@Zack  Phantom voltage is a thing.  It just needs to be close to a good hot/live wire to make a dead wire look live.  With some christmas light strings it can be easier to buy a new set than trying to find the broken light or wire.  A broken wire inside insulation can be the hardest to find, you only have so many lights to check, but every inch of the wires.
